# Executing multiple SSRS reports from SSIS package

Tags: reporting-services, ssis

I have developed an SSIS package to run 3 reports from Reporting Services that are data driven subscriptions.

When I run the SSIS job it executes all the 3 reports at once, what I need is to run the reports sequentially, in other words, one by one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behavior. When you trigger a data driven subscription job, the SQL Server Agent starts the job and that completes the whole transaction. The SSIS package would then go on to trigger the next data driven subscription job and the next ( assuming you have put the job-triggering in sequence).

Now if you want to create a dependency in the way the jobs should run i.e. Job1 followed by Job2 followed by Job3, you need to manually write additional piece of code. The way to go about it would be to monitor the status code of the subscription.

In the ReportServer database there is a table called dbo.Subscriptions containing a column 'LastStatus'. Currently in my local db, I don't have any subscriptions and also am not able to find any documentation for the table. But I am pretty sure this would be either a boolean or a status flag such as 'Sucess' or 'Failure. Upon triggering the first job, you would need to write a .net Code to monitor this status with a polling interval. Once you get the desired outcome, move on to triggering the next job.

Hope this is clear. I would edit this answer with an working example.

Comment: Thanks VKarthik, I am not a .net programmer, I hope you can provide the codes.

Comment: The flag values are: Done: 1 processed of 1 total; 0 errors, or Pending or Error: This report requires ....